# Basic Algebra Proof on Integers - Weak Inequalities Work but Strict Inequalities Don't?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Let $a, b, \& \, m$ be integers. Prove that if $2a + 3b \geq 12m + 1$, then $a \geq 3m + 1$ or $b \geq 2m + 1$.

**My Attempt:** I don't conceive apace how to contrive, from the one inequality in the antecedent, the two inequalities in the consequent. So a proof by contraposition may be more facile. The contrapositive is: $\text{If }  \color{Green}{a < 3m + 1} \; \& \; \color{#0073CF}{b < 2m + 1}, \text{ then } 2a + 3b < 12m + 1 \tag{*}.$

From $(*)$, $\color{Green}{2a} + \color{#0073CF}{3b} < \color{Green}{6m + 2} \; + \;\color{#0073CF}{6m + 3} = 12m +5$. But this doesn't prove $(*)$.

> **Given Solution:**  Assume that $a < 3m+1$ and $b < 2m+1.$ Since a and b are integers, $a ≤ 3m$ and $b ≤ 2m.$ Therefore, $2a + 3b ≤ 2(3m) + 3(2m) = 12m < 12m+ 1,$ as desired. $\blacksquare$

What went wrong in my attempt? I understand the given solution but I persisted with the more natural and direct green and blue, instead of deviating to weak inequalities. Shouldn't both solutions work?

Source: Problem 4.19 on P102 (related to P90, Result 4.8) of *Mathematical Proofs, 2nd ed* by Chartrand et al.

---

$\large{\text{Supplement to Cameron Buie and pritam's Answers :}}$

What overriding, catholic lessons can be extrapolated from this example to generalise about inequalities?

Moreover, in order to circumvent the problem here (ie the loss of information from the weaker inequalities), should I always start with the strictest inequality? If so, should I always rework any weak inequality into the equivalent strict inequality?

For example, define $r \in \mathbb{R} $ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $g(...) \neq h(...)$. Then $ f(r) < h(r) \require{enclose}
     \enclose{updiagonalstrike}{\iff} f(r) \leq g(r).$
But $ f(n) < h(n) \text{ MAY OR MAY NOT }\iff f(n) \leq g(n).$

Comment: The key to the problem is that you are dealing with integers. You are basically trying to prove the statement for real numbers.

Comment: In fact, they are deviating to *stronger* inequalities (in general, though they are equivalent over the integers), which allow the proof to go off.

Comment: When you multiply a strict inequality for integers by some integer you get some extra "solutions": for integers
$a < 2$ and $a \le 1$ are equivalent, but $3a<6$ and $3a \le 3$ are not.

Comment: @njguliyev: Thank you. Could you please expound on your comment, especially in the general case?

Comment: @njguliyev: Actually, if you know that $a$ is an integer, then $3a<6$ and $3a\le 3$ are still equivalent. See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested, I will expound upon my comment, but I'll do it in the form of an answer, since it's rather lengthy.

I noted that the given proof deviates to *stronger* inequalities, which allow the proof to work. By that I mean, for example, that if $a$ and $m$ are integers, then $a<3m+1$ if and only if $a\le 3m.$ They are not equivalent among real numbers (take $m=1$ and $a=3.5,$ for example), but the inequality $a\le 3m$ *implies* the inequality $a<3m+1$, meaning $a\le 3m$ is the *stronger* of the two inequalities, despite being non-strict.

What if we multiply both inequalities by $2$? Then we're dealing with $2a\le 6m$ and $2a<6m+2.$ **These are still equivalent** if we know that $a,m$ are integers, but it isn't as obvious why, since one of them is misleading. The kicker is divisibility. We already know that there are no integers in the interval $(6m+1,6m+2)$ since $m$ is an integer, which lets us rewrite $2a<6m+2$ equivalently as $2a\le 6m+1$. Since $a$ and $m$ are integers, though, we have that $2a$ is even and $6m+1=2(3m)+1$ is odd, so we can't have equality. Hence, we rewrite it equivalently as $2a<6m+1,$ which in turn yields $2m\le 6m.$

Similarly, taking $b,m$ to be integers, $3b<6m+3$ yields $3b\le 6m+2;$ since $3$ divides $3b$ and does not divide $6m+2=3(2m)+2,$ then we have $3b<6m+2,$ which in turn yields $3b\le 6m+1;$ but $3$ does not divide $6m+1=3(2m)+1,$ so this yields $3b<6m+1,$ which in turn yields $3b\le 6m.$

Why did the strengthened forms of the inequalities work when the others didn't? Well, quite simply because the "weaker" versions weren't precise enough--they were suggesting more room to maneuver than there actually was, so once we "added the inequalities together" we had an inequality that was too weak, and didn't clearly imply our desired result. Indeed, as you saw, once we put $2a<6m+2$ and $3b<6m+3$ together to get $2a+3b<12m+5,$ we're out of luck. That extra pad in the strict inequalities left us with a $5$ that we can't get rid of--simple divisibility arguments won't let us remove it the way we did above, because it isn't clear what numbers should divide $2a+3b$. However, with the "strictest" versions of the inequalities, we simply get $2a+3b\le12m,$ which readily yields the desired conclusion.

Comment: I'd say the upshot is this: When dealing with integer inequalities, use the "strongest" form possible (judged in terms of real number inequalities), even if there are "weaker" equivalent forms. You'll be able to prove things more easily.

Comment: Thank you again. I updated my supplement with an Example. So do you mean using $f(n) \leq g(n)$, IF $f(n) \leq g(n) \iff f(n) < h(n)$? I reckon this is the case here with $f(a) = 2a$ and $f(b) = 3b$?

Comment: If I understand your (pseudo)example correctly: Yes, when working over the integers, rework your inequalities to the strongest (in the real sense) possible equivalent (in the integer sense) form.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am buffaloed by "rework your inequalities to the strongest (in the real sense) possible equivalent (in the integer sense) form." Could you please elucidate? Also, are there any paramount lessons on real number inequalities from my OP?

Comment: By that, I mean (for example), that for integers $b,m,$ all of the following *uncountably infinitely many* inequalities are in fact equivalent (where $r$ is a real number with $0<r<3$): $$3b<6m+r$$ $$3b\le 6m+r$$ $$3b\le 6m$$
Now, if we're dealing with real numbers $b,m,$ then the last inequality is **strictly stronger** than the others. However, the next strongest (in the real sense) inequality is $3b<6m,$ which is (in the integer sense) **strictly stronger** than the others. That is what I mean by being strongest in the real sense, while still being equivalent in the integer sense.

Comment: At this point, it's probably worth asking, do you understand what I mean by one inequality being stronger than another (in the real sense)? For example, if $x,y$ are real numbers, is $x<y$ or $x\le y$ stronger? What about $x\le y$ and $x<y+1$?

Comment: Many thanks. I upvoted. Is it correct to esteem "stronger", coloured in green, as the more restrictive and thus informatory inequality?  $\color{green}{x < y} \Longrightarrow \require{enclose}
     \enclose{updiagonalstrike}{\Longleftarrow} x \leq y$. Also, $\color{green}{x \leq y} \Longrightarrow \require{enclose}
     \enclose{updiagonalstrike}{\Longleftarrow} x < y + 1$

Comment: Moreover, is "the others" in "which is (in the integer sense) **strictly stronger** than the others": $$3b < 6m + r \quad \text{ where $r$ is a real number $\in (0, 3)$} \qquad ? $$ You are intimating that $3b < 6m$ is stronger than all of these *uncountably infinitely many* inequalities?

Comment: Yes, on the first count. The second is correct statement, but let me rephrase to make sure we're on the same page. Now, $3b\le 6m$ is equivalent to all of the uncountably many inequalities $3b<6m+r$ and all of the uncountably many inequalities $3b\le 6m+r$ when $b,m$ are integers and $r$ lies in the real interval $(0,3).$ $3b\le 6m$ is strictly stronger than all of them when $b,m$ are real numbers. $3b<6m$ is indeed stronger than $3b\le 6m$ and *all* of the above-mentioned uncountably many inequalities, *regardless* of whether $b,m$ are integers or reals.

Comment: I thank you immensely for your Answer and comments! Regrettably, I wish I could upvote $> 1$ but I'll pore through your other answers whose quality presumably must $\geq$ than that delineated here. Your persistent, prompt care and fidelity to me $> \infty$! I thank you infinitely again!

Comment: Always glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

What went wrong with your solution was that you didn't use the fact that $a$, $b$ and $m$ are integers. If they were real numbers the inequality $2a+3b\ge12m+1$ would not imply the conclusion given.

For example, if $m=1$, $a=3.5$, $b= 2.5$ we have $2\times 3.5 + 3\times 2.5 = 7+7.5=14.5 \ge 13$.

The solution given does use the fact that the numbers are integers - the next integer down from $a$ is $a-1$, and you can't have $a-\frac 12$.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain why your attempt doesn't work. From your assumptions $a<3m+1$ & $b<2m+1$ you can write $$a=3m+1-x\quad\&\quad b=2m+1-y$$ where $x,y>0$. Then , $$2a+3b=12m+5-(2x+3y)$$ Now note that, if you don't use the fact that $x,y$ are integers, then you only get $2x+3y>0$, which is what you did. If you use the fact that $x,y$ are integers then you will get $$2x+3y\geq2\cdot 1+3\cdot 1=5$$ so $2a+3b\leq 12m+5-5=12m$.

Comment: Thank you. I understand that if $x \, \& \, y$ are esteemed as real numbers, rather than integers, then $2a + 3b = 12m + 5 - \underbrace{(2x + 3y)}_{\large{> \, 0}}$. However, would you please care to explicate "what is what you did"? I didn't allude to this?